# String Array, increase chances of a certain string being picked?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm fairly new to this whole thing. I'm making a program that will prompt the user to enter a name, it will then store this name in an array (size of array is 4) and then randomly pick a name and display it.

I'm wondering how I can increase the chances of a certain name being picked, for example, I enter
Bob,
Jim,
John,
Tim,
into the array, is it possible for Bob to have an increased chance in being picked? I'm not sure where to begin or what to even do, I've searched everywhere.

Comment: Increase the size of the array, have Bob listed more than once.

Comment: What do you have so far? How are you picking them as of now?

Comment: Of course its possible, but you have to define what makes "Bob" more likely to be picked. Are you using a weighted distribution, is it just something special about the name, multiple instances of the name in the list? You haven't found enough requirements yet.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET it seems to me that it would be sufficient just to specify the (greater) probability for Bob to be picked to arrive at a solution.  We don't really need to know *why*, the probability is higher, do we?

Comment: @phoog Then we end up with answers like the one from Jame's .. which while true doesn't really go anywhere exciting, including the OPs understanding of the problem/approaches.

Comment: @phoog I assumed that the given code was a trivial example. I've done this using beta and inverse exponential distributions in industry, but thats because our requirements called for it. The reason for doing this would seem to drive the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is fairly straightforward.

- Make simple class that holds the weight of the name
- Initialize a list of all the names and their weight (it's up to you to define what dictates weight).
- For each name, add it to main array based on it's X weight.
- Randomly get an index between 0 and the upperbounds of the array.

```
public class NameOption
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Weight { get; set; }

     public NameOption(string name, int weight)
     {
         Name = name;
         Weight = weight;
     }
}

// Will need the System.Linq namespace declared in order to use the LINQ statements
public string PickName()
{
    var nameOptions = new List<NameOption> 
                {
                    new NameOption("Bob",5),
                    new NameOption("John", 1),
                    etc...
                };
    // FYI - following won't work if Weight was a negative value or 0.
    var namesToPickFrom = new string[nameOptions.Sum(x => x.Weight)];
    var nameIndex = 0;
    foreach (var option in nameOptions)
    {
       for (var i = 0; i < option.Weight; i++)
           namesToPickFrom[nameIndex++] = option.Name;
    }
    var random = new Random();
    return namesToPickFrom[random.Next(0, namesToPickFrom.Length-1)];
}
```

Comment: Try LINQPad or ideone for testing coding quickly.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks. I think I found my new favorite tool. :D

Answer (score 0):

Easy --- cheat.

Instead of picking a number (0-3), pick one (0-4), and if you get 4, use 0.

Comment: That has to be the cheapest weighted distribution ever ;)

Comment: Doesn't even need an `if`, just modulo it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't searched enough because that's pretty easy and a well-known probability problem.
To keep it as simple as possible just use two arrays, one with the names and another with a positive integer.

It doesn't matter what values the integers have as long as they represent the **weight** of being picked. That's a relative measure of the probability.

Now sum them:

```
i = 0;
sum = 0;
while (i < prob.Length)
{
    sum += prob[i];
}

pick = rnd.Next(sum); // 0..sum-1

i = 0;
while (pick >= prob[i])
{
    pick -= prob[i];
    i++;
}

// i is now the index of the name picked
```

Answer (score 0):

For each name store a percentage that it will be picked. Make sure the percentages add up to 100.
Assign ranges to each name based on the percentage.

Pseudo Example:

```
Bob = 50%
Jim = 10%
John = 20%
Tim = 20%

//Have your code assign Ranges Based on the percentage:
Bob: Low=1, High=50
Jim: Low=51, High=60
John: Low=61, High=80
Tim: Low=81, High=100

//Get a random number between 1 and 100. Use if-elses to return the matching name.
```